# How should I go about updating a RecyclerView's data set and notifying the adapter from the view holder?

Tags: java, android

I have a list of posts built using a RecyclerView. The classes that I have for this scenario are a fragment, the adapter and the view holder. When the fragment is loaded I get the list of posts from an API call using okhttp and pass the list to the adapter.

For each item in the list I have a context menu which I'm defining in the view holder like this.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Actions");

        if (!post.isRemoved()) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Move to Trash")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(onTrashMenu);
        }
        else {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Delete")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(onDeleteMenu);

            menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Restore")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(onRestoreMenu);
        }
    }
```

Also, every listener is in the view holder class. For example:

```
private final MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener onDeleteMenu = item -> {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "SOME_URL";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .delete()
                .header("SOME_HEADER")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.e("POSTS_VIEW_HOLDER", e.getMessage());
                Snackbar.make(PostViewHolder.super.itemView, "Failed to remove post.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                Snackbar.make(PostViewHolder.super.itemView, "Post removed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        return true;
    };
```

I've tried using an interface in the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434674/5867861).

Adapter's constructor requires the interface as an argument. And then I pass it further to the view holder when I create it.

```
public PostsAdapter(Post[] posts, AdapterInterface adapterInterface) {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.adapterInterface = adapterInterface;
    }

@NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View postItemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.post_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new PostViewHolder(postItemView, adapterInterface);
    }
```

Passed from the fragment like this:

```
postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(null, this::loadPosts);
```

The loadPosts() method uses okhttp and in the callback sets the adapter's data set and calls .notifyDataSetChanged().

When calling the method from the interface in the view holder I got this:

> only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

So I used a handler to get around it:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

mHandler.post(() -> {
                    adapterInterface.dataSetChanged();
                });
```

But now, whenever this method is called, nothing happens. I would like to know if what I've done makes some sense and also, if there's a better way (or, at least, one that's working) to go about this.

**Edit**

loadPosts() implementation:

```
public void loadPosts() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();

        this.client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    final Post[] posts = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), Post[].class);

                    mHandler.post(() -> {
                        postsAdapter.setPosts(posts);
                        postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    });
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where is your loadPosts implementation?

Comment: @Rookie In the fragment.

Comment: Can you post it here?

Comment: @Rookie Sure, done.

Comment: First thing is you should check whether you are getting the data in the response. And if you are getting then only should you pass it to adapter.
Are you sure you are getting the data? Because everything looks fine here. Just debug the loadPosts method and see.

Comment: @Rookie Thanks for the tip. Now it's working. notifyDataSetChanged() wasn't working as expected for some reason so I had to use notifyItemRemoved() and notifyItemChanged().